# How to cache API calls on dev in Angular?

Tags: angular

Angular uses webpack dev server as a proxy to an actual API. API is sometimes slow. It makes debugging integration and user tests slow. How to introduce a cache for API calls that works only while development and stores cache so that it is used also after application reload?

Comment: I see no one has answer. So i wrote my own. It will be much more helpful than downvoting or voting for closing without any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. It is possible to use a proxy with caching functionality like for example Squid.

Another solution is to use webpack-dev-server that is part of Angular to add cache functionality. Unfortunately, the webpack-dev-server is poorly documented and it's almost impossible to add such functionality.

But there is a way to accomplish it. In your application code you need to modify your get handler:

```
devCacheGet = true && !environment.production;
get(url: string, ...) { //generic get handler in your service handling all get calls
  if (devCacheGet) {
     if (localStorage.getItem("devCache" + url)) {
         return localStorage.getItem(JSON.parse("devCache" + url));
     }
  }

  result = callAPI(...);
  if (devCacheGet) {
      localStorage.setItem("devCache" + url, JSON.stringify(result));
  }
  return result;
}
```

The code has to be modified to handle Observables if you use if and adjusted to your code base. But more or less it is the idea.

You can enable cache with true/false in devCacheGet. Second part of the condition blocks the devCache to be enabled in production stage.

The cons of this solution is that you need to remember is on (i put a warning in console to remember).

Pros is that when working on near integration parts you work on real data from API. So it makes debugging faster. If you make 5 calls each for 2 seconds = 10 seconds. With this solution the time for load data drops to 5x20ms = 100ms. You save 9,9 second on each page load.

It won't replace unit tests and integration tests, but it is very helpful in specific set of situations.